# Facilitating shorthand referencing for linked server with synonyms

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, linked-server, sql-server-2016

I'm using a linked server and finding it very painful to write queries like this:

```
select * from [10.150.10.109].lhf.[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
```

Is it possible to use a synonym for something like this:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [DataRelay] FOR [10.150.10.109].[lhf].[dbo]
```

in order to be able to query like this:

```
select * from DataRelay.TABLE_NAME
```

[Without the capabilities of Intellisense](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2c67e6c5-bd07-412f-80ed-c3e94e3c2967/is-intellisense-on-linked-server-possible?forum=sqltools), this is just painful...

Comment: Just make better names for your linked servers.  The LinkedServer name does *not* have to match the actual server name.

Comment: nope, but you can easily script the creation of synonyms for objects in your database at your linked server.  just use [servername].[dbname].sys.objects and dynamic sql to do so

Comment: @Matt, could you please clarify what you meant?

Comment: @Eliezer see my answer below

Comment: @Matt, that was *so* much clearer! :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I had a minute what I was saying in my comment is that you cannot create a synonym for just part of an object path as you desire.  But you can dynamically script the drop and creation of synonyms for any object in your remote database pretty easily.  here is an example of how to do if for user tables.  For other objects you can use the sys.objects instead of sys.table system view.

Technique key words for more learning.  Dynamic SQL, cursor, schema views.

```
DECLARE @ServerAndDB SYSNAME = '[10.150.10.109].[lhf]'
DECLARE @SynonymSchema SYSNAME = '[syn]'

DECLARE @ObjectPath NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @SynonymName NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE CursorName CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
       @ServerAndDB + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) as ObjectPath
       ,@SynonymSchema + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) as SynonymName
    FROM
       [10.150.10.109].[lhf].sys.tables t
    WHERE
       t.type = 'U'

OPEN CursorName

FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName
INTO @ObjectPath, @SynonymName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

       BEGIN TRY

            DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.synonyms WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@SynonymName))
            BEGIN
             SET @SQL = 'DROP SYNONYM ' + @SynonymName
             EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
             SET @SQL = ''
            END

            SET @SQL = 'CREATE SYNONYM ' + @SynonymName + ' FOR ' + @ObjectPath
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
            SET @SQL = ''

       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
          --Can do error handling here
       END CATCH

       FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName
       INTO @ObjectPath, @SynonymName
    END

CLOSE CursorName
DEALLOCATE CursorName
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no short hand for linked servers, however, you can alias tables in your queries to make it a bit easier.

```
select * from [10.150.10.109].lhf.[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] T
WHERE
   T.FieldName=1
   OR
   T.FieldName=2
```